# Software interrupt

Tags: c, interrupt

How can I program software interrupt in C? I know need to write an interrupt servicing routine and then interrupt the CPU so that the routine can be called, but I don't know how to do that in C. Also, I don't know how to register that routine with Interrupt descriptor table.
I have an x86-64 CPU (AMD Turion64 X2) and I am using gcc compiler.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The things you're asking how to do are things you do when writing an operating system, not an application. Could you explain a little bit more about what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Actually, I am working on an assignment for my faculty, I need to examine IRET instruction, that's why I need an interrupt servicing routine. After I've written it, I am supposed to "play" with executable file's hex code and alter the IRET (delete it or something) in order to see what happens.

Comment: You can't write ISRs in C, it requires (some) assembly.  You can't test ISRs on a protected mode operating system.  Altering the IRET will just crash the code.  Talk to your educator about this assignment.

Answer (score 3):

The concept of interrupts is not included in the C specification (and is also somewhat processor specific). Most compilers, including GCC, let you write inline assembly code (or you can of course link a file written in assembly to your program). But the big problem is that common operating systems (especially those running in 64-bit mode) will not let you alter the interrupt table. I guess your best bet is to look for a simple open source OS and either install your interrupt handler from a normal program (if the OS allows it) or add your code to the kernel. The reason why you can't just run a small piece of code in a processor simulator (or virtual machine) is that the processor needs quite a bit of setup to get into 64-bit mode. And the exact details about how you alter the interrupt table depends on that setup.

Answer (score 1):

The operating system hides real interrupts from applications. As far as I know it isn't possible unless you are running in the kernel layer (ring 0?)

Answer (score 0):

Use `sigaction`. See `man 2 sigaction`.

To cause the interrupt, use `raise` or `kill`.

Comment: This doesn't do the job, it does not make real interrupt. In case I was unclear, I am supposed to interrupt the CPU, not the application.

Answer (score 0):

writting ISR is not a matter of Language. yes you can do it in C.

Its a matter of Understanding of your OS Kernel, about routines that are called to register your ISR on a certain interrupt line with GIC or other interrupt controllers and make an Entry in Interrupt Descriptor table .
Like with Linux on ARM .. Its request_irq() to register an ISR with IRQ contoller and make an entry in IRQ_DESC table.

So will suggest first check ISR framework of your respective OS.